# Webservice to save data to Json format

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I am new to webservice in dot net and i am trying to save the data in Json format ,Below is the code of my service.asmx file, Here i am getting the data from the database, but i don't have the idea how to save the data in Json format. Pls guide me with a solution for this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace JSONWeb
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]

    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]


    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public DataSet SelectData()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HOME;database=Data;Integrated Security=true");
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            SqlDataAdapter da;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectData", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod]
    public void SaveData(string name, string address)
    {
        try{
            string connectionString ='';
            connectionString='';//Your connection string
             using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                //Create the SqlCommand object
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_SaveData", con);

                //Specify that the SqlCommand is a stored procedure
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //Add the input parameters to the command object
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", address.Trim());


                //Open the connection and execute the query
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }


    function SaveData(name,address) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "service.asmx/SaveData",//Give full path upto the webservice
            data: JSON2.stringify({ name: name, address: address }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert('Data saved success');
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert('Data saved failed');
            }

        });
    }
```

You can call SaveData function from js file on button click and save data